# What is the difference between "some would argue that..." vs "some may argue that"?

Tags: meaning, word-choice, modal-verbs

What is the difference between these two expressions:
"Some would argue that..." vs "Some may argue that..."
Thank you,

Comment: I think they're largely interchangeable. I'd use 'Some would argue that' to introduce a counter-argument with which I agreed, 'Some might argue that' to introduce an argument I'd go on to attack.

Comment: Can you give me some examples?

Comment: Would is in the simple past tense (compare the definite claim of *'Some will argue that'*) and expresses a less definite approach to the claim. It is part of a hidden conditional: *If they were asked*, some would argue that....' Thus "would" introduces a strong possibility. **May** is in the present tense and expresses an ambivalent degree possibility, as it can be read as "may or may not."

Comment: There is a subtle difference here.  The first, with 'would', can be used to express a tendency ("would, if you asked them").  This implies, I think, that what follows is an opinion that has been expressed by some people and is worth considering.  The second, with 'may', suggests a possible opinion worth considering but not necessarily so far expressed.  Perhaps the person addressed has an idea about something and the speaker is suggesting possible responses that different people might have.

Comment: << Prestigious dictionaries often pronounce on parts of speech and how words must be used in constructions. Some would argue that recognised grammars such as MaCauley must be seen as more authoritative in these areas. They are, after all, written by the experts in the field of grammar. >>  // <<  'Several', 'many', 'some' and other quantifiers are in the determiner / determinative word-class, though some might still argue that they're adjectives. >>

Comment: I would choose *might* over *may* … and [Google Ngram Viewer](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=some+might+argue%2C+some+would+argue%2C+some+may+argue&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Csome%20might%20argue%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Csome%20would%20argue%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Csome%20may%20argue%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Csome%20might%20argue%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Csome%20would%20argue%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Csome%20may%20argue%3B%2Cc0) agrees, although *would* is the most common.

Comment: Thank you. I appreciate your taking the time to answer my question.